# Why use typeof for identifying a function?

Tags: javascript

Are there any significant reasons for using

```
typeof variable === 'function'
```

versus

```
!!variable.call
```

for detecting if a variable is a function?

Other than the obvious one that someone may create an object like:

```
{ call: 1 }
```

The problem that I have is that

```
typeof /regex/ === 'function'
```

returns true, but

```
!!/regex/.call
```

returns false

Comment: I believe your solution is better.

Comment: Um, do you want to say that `typeof /regex/ === 'function'` yields *true*?

Comment: @Gumbo it does in chrome. It's absurd.

Comment: why not `function(){} instanceof Function`?

Comment: @Worm Regards: I tried using instanceof on a function just now in Chrome. Got "Uncaught TypeError: Expecting a function in instanceof check, but got function foo() {}" Um...?

Comment: @Gumbo RegExp objects implement [[Call]] in all browsers, as far as I know. Returning 'object' for this is in violation of ES5.

Comment: @gsnedders: No, *RegExp* objects do not implement [[Call]]. Just take a look in the ECMAScript specification 5th edition at chapter 15.10 that describes *RegExp* objects.

Comment: @Gumbo I did not say ES5 specifies RegExp objects to implement [[Call]]. I said that browsers implement [[Call]] on RegExp object. These are two different statements.

Comment: @gsnedders: Ah ok. Well then you’re right.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The safest way is to check the internal [[Class]] property by setting the object as the *thisArg* argument of the `.call()` method when calling `Object.prototype.toString`.

```
Object.prototype.toString.call( myVariable ) === '[object Function]';
```

Of course you could easily make a function out of it:

```
function checkClass( obj ) {
    return Object.prototype.toString.call( obj ).slice( 8, -1).toLowerCase();
}

checkClass( myVariable ) === 'function';
```

This is very simple, and there could be some improvements, but you get the idea.

Comment: This works unless you redefine the internal `Object.prototype.toString` function. ;)

Comment: Could you take a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5055061/null-undefined-are-replaced-with-the-global-object-in-all-browsers-except-ie9 ?

Comment: @Gumbo: I missed your comment earlier. Good point. Can't we have just one bit of certainty in javascript?!

Comment: This solution does not work for IE8 and below. Since those browser will think built-in function as object. Please check: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8100444/why-some-built-in-functions-in-ie8-are-not-instances-of-function

Comment: This is a horrible solution for not being able to work regardless of modifying or redefining built-in properties. `Object.prototype.toString = function () {}` breaks this.

Answer (score 5):

According to the ECMAScript specification, the following should apply for [regular expression literals](http://bclary.com/2004/11/07/#a-7.8.5):

> A regular expression literal is an input element that is converted to a *RegExp* object ([section 15.10](http://bclary.com/2004/11/07/#a-15.10)) when it is scanned. The object is created before evaluation of the containing program or function begins.

So `typeof /regex/` should yield `"object"`:

```
typeof /regex/ === "object"
```

And the constructor of the object created by the regular expression literal should be *RegExp*:

```
/regex/.constructor === RegExp
```

Similar to that, a [function definition](http://bclary.com/2004/11/07/#a-13) should yield a *Function* object:

```
(function(){}).constructor === Function
```

But although this returns a *Function* object, the [`typeof` operator](http://bclary.com/2004/11/07/#a-11.4.3) should not yield `"object"` but `"function"` instead:

```
typeof function(){} === "function"
```

This is due to the distinction whether the object implements the [internal *[[Call]]* property](http://bclary.com/2004/11/07/#a-13.2.1) that is special for [*Function* objects](http://bclary.com/2004/11/07/#a-13.2).

Note that all this is how Javascript implementations *should* behave. So all equations are asserted to be true.

Answer (score 2):

Check the assumptions in the post (see Gumbo's comment).

```
typeof /regex/ === 'function'
```

This returns `false` in Firefox 3.6.13.

Just for amusement, Firefox 3.6.13:

```
typeof /regex/                    // "object"
/regex/ instanceof RegExp         // true
/regex/.constructor.name          // RegExp
(function () {}).constructor.name // Function
```

IE8:

```
typeof /regex/                    // "object"
/regex/ instanceof RegExp         // true
/regex/.constructor.name          // undefined
(function () {}).constructor.name // undefined
```

Chrome 9:

```
typeof /regex/                    // "function"
/regex/ instanceof RegExp         // true
/regex/.constructor.name          // "RegExp"
(function () {}).constructor.name // "Function"
```

Comment: In Chrome 10 it evaluates to true.

Answer (score 2):

A regular expression is a function

`/bar/("bar") === ["bar"]`

So `typeof /bar/ === "function"`

Although only chrome recognises that a regexp literal can be used as a function. Whether this should be so or not is up for grabs. You can treat it just like a function!

Comment: That's interesting. I didn't know you could do that.

Comment: @patrickdw you mean damn thats confusing! I know have to start thinking of RegExp literals as functions instead of objects.

Comment: This is only a proprietary extension. In ECMAScript, regular expressions are objects.

Answer (score 1):

[jQuery's `isFunction`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.isFunction/) avoids the `RegExp` problem you mention by `toString`-ing the object and checking the result against a map of known types. From the [latest source](http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js), here's the map:

```
// Populate the class2type map
jQuery.each("Boolean Number String Function Array Date RegExp Object".split(" "), function(i, name) {
    class2type[ "[object " + name + "]" ] = name.toLowerCase();
});
```

And here's how it's used:

```
type: function( obj ) {
    return obj == null ?
        String( obj ) :
        class2type[ toString.call(obj) ] || "object";
},

// See test/unit/core.js for details concerning isFunction.
// Since version 1.3, DOM methods and functions like alert
// aren't supported. They return false on IE (#2968).
isFunction: function( obj ) {
    return jQuery.type(obj) === "function";
},
```

You can learn a lot reading the jQuery source.

- http://james.padolsey.com/jquery/#v=1.5.0&fn=jQuery.isFunction
- http://james.padolsey.com/jquery/#v=1.5.0&fn=jQuery.type

Comment: very smelly and stringly typed, -1 for suggesting to learn from it (BTW, monkey style array initializer 6-8 times slower than regular unlazy literal)

Comment: @Worm - appreciate the explanation for the -1. I disagree that the performance issue here is worth worrying about and think there's still something to learn here, even if you decide not to use it. But thanks for the time to explain.

Comment: You'll note that the accepted and top-voted answer uses a less general version of the jQuery approach I described.

Comment: Well, sure, top answer exercises "string typization" too. Anyway, pattern is same as `boolean.toString().length == 4`

Comment: Complaining that this is "stringly typed" is a little unfair. JavaScript's `typeof` is notoriously broken. It's not as though we're ignoring clearly better alternatives. Google provides the following definition for "stringly typed": "A riff on strongly-typed. Used to describe an implementation that needlessly relies on strings when programmer- and refactor-friendly options are available." 1) This isn't needless. 2) Programmer- and refactor-friendly options are not available.

Comment: IMHO code like this is as bad as `eval("var "+name+"="+value";")` but sadly jquery is very popular.

Comment: -1. jQuery is a fabulous way to degrade the performance of any basic operation by one or two orders of magnitude. This is only one example. In all but a handful of cases in the entire history of the universe, `typeof f==="function"` does exactly what you want and does it many times faster than alternatives. Please quit whining.

Comment: In all but a handful of cases in the entire history of the universe the performance issue debated here doesn't matter

Comment: I like this answer just because I noticed that $.type(/test/) === "regexp" is available if you are using jQuery.  And no, this isn't a vote for jQuery.  I upvoted the top answer too.  :)

Answer (score -1):

`typeof variable === 'function'` is better than `!!variable.call` because if variable is undefined or null, `!!variable.call` will throw an error.