# null/undefined are replaced with the global object in all browsers except IE9

Tags: javascript, browser

When I do this:

```
Object.prototype.toString.call( null )
```

or this:

```
Object.prototype.toString.call( )
```

the browsers return the following string value (in both cases):

Chrome 9: `[object global]`
Safari 5: `[object DOMWindow]`
Firefox 3.6: `[object Window]`
Opera 11: `[object Window]`

However in IE9 RC the return values are `[object Null]` and `[object Undefined]` respectively.

The ES5 specification states:

> NOTE The thisArg value is passed
>   without modification as the this
>   value. This is a change from Edition
>   3, where a undefined or null thisArg
>   is replaced with the global object and
>   ToObject is applied to all other
>   values and that result is passed as
>   the this value.

See here: http://es5.github.com/#x15.3.4.4

Does this mean that IE9 is the only browser that follows this newly introduced rule?

Comment: Great observation! May I ask how you came across this? I guess this means that you have to check for null before using call()...

Comment: @Mark Well I've read patrick's answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5054352/why-use-typeof-for-identifying-a-function/5054416#5054416 and than started to pass in all kinds of values into `Object.prototype.toString.call` to test the cross-browser compatibility of retrieving the `[[Class]]` internal property of an object. Check out my observations here: http://vidasp.net/javascript-internal-class.html

Comment: Looking at your test, I was surprised to see that JSON was reported as `Object`, especially since Math was reported properly. So I thought maybe jsFiddle was overwriting the native JSON implementation. Sure enough, testing it in the console while StackOverflow is loaded, I get `[object JSON]`.

Comment: ...Correction, looks like MooTools is the culprit. Testing with no library loaded gives the proper result. http://jsfiddle.net/e4cP9/6/

Comment: @patrick Cool, I didn't know about the "No-library" option.

Answer (score 3):

I'm going to go out on a limb and say *yes*. ;)

FYI, I just tested FF4, and it gives `[object Null]` and `[object Undefined]`

Comment: Yes, FF4 and IE9 it is. The other browsers should follow soon. Funny though how Google released 6 versions of Chrome since the ES5 publication, and still nothing `:)`

Comment: Šime Vidas: Yes, I'm surprised by that. When I saw your question, I upgraded to Chrome 10 beta, and still the same.