# Can i use constructor.name to detect types in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, types, detection, typeof

Can I use the "constructor" property to detect types in JavaScript?
Or is there something I should know about it.

For example: `var a = {}; a.constructor.name; // outputs "Object"`

or `var b = 1; b.constructor.name; // outputs "Number"`

or `var d = new Date(); d.constructor.name; // outputs "Date" not Object`

or `var f = new Function(); f.constructor.name; // outputs "Function" not Object`

only if use it on arguments `arguments.constructor.name; //outputs Object like first example`

I see quite often developers using: `Object.prototype.toString.call([])` or

`Object.prototype.toString.call({})`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [`typeof`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Special/typeof), but it returns [misleading](http://bonsaiden.github.com/JavaScript-Garden/#types.typeof) [results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5054352/why-use-typeof-for-identifying-a-function) sometimes. Instead, use `Object.prototype.toString.call(obj)`, which uses the object's internal `[[Class]]` property. You can even make a simple wrapper for it, so it acts similar to `typeof`:

```
function TypeOf(obj) {
  return Object.prototype.toString.call(obj).slice(8, -1).toLowerCase();
}

TypeOf("String") === "string"
TypeOf(new String("String")) === "string"
TypeOf(true) === "boolean"
TypeOf(new Boolean(true)) === "boolean"
TypeOf({}) === "object"
TypeOf(function(){}) === "function"
```

Don't use `obj.constructor` because it be changed, although you *might* be able to use `instanceof` to see if it is correct:

```
function CustomObject() {
}
var custom = new CustomObject();
//Check the constructor
custom.constructor === CustomObject
//Now, change the constructor property of the object
custom.constructor = RegExp
//The constructor property of the object is now incorrect
custom.constructor !== CustomObject
//Although instanceof still returns true
custom instanceof CustomObject === true
```

Comment: @gruentee [citation needed]

Works just fine for me in IE11

Answer (score 1):

You can use `typeof`
Ex: `typeof("Hello")`

Comment: typeof won´t actually so precise because `alert ( typeof new Number() ) // Object`

Comment: Agree, because JavaScript is not a typed language you cannt expect its typeof to be precise :)

Comment: No, JavaScript is a loosely typed language.

Comment: Are you sure??? `typeof` opertaor is the best choise to find out is the variable istantiated or not(or is is it exists, there are some issues too) but if i have something like that: `var a = function() {}; var b = new a(); typeof a; //outputs object` or `typeof new Array(); //outputs object`. so how can i use to make it precisely?