# _.isFunction(a) vs. typeof a === 'function'? javascript

Tags: javascript, performance, underscore.js, typeof

I think it might be only performance case - http://jsperf.com/comparing-underscore-js-isfunction-with-typeof-function/2

And seems that `typeof` is faster.. so my question is - which is more appropriate to use?

Comment: See the answers here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5999998/how-can-i-check-if-a-javascript-variable-is-function-type

Answer (score 102, accepted):

There is no reason not to use `typeof`.

Not only is it faster but the [ECMAScript specification](http://es5.github.io/#x11.4.3) ensures that all functions have a type of "function" and that only functions can have a type of "function" :

[image]

This operator was specifically designed to get the type of a value, so why not use it ?

Comment: @Kosmetika I don't get your comment.

Comment: I mean that there need to be a points to use ``isFunction()`` or maybe even ``instanceof Function`` for example

Comment: @Kosmetika As Dogbert points, there **was** a bug in old versions of Chrome. Now you just should use `typeof`.

Comment: Well. All perfect and this is the right answer, but I would argue that using _.isFunction() is more legible for a newcomer reading the source code.

Also, there's no big difference at performance.

Comment: What is a "host" object?

Answer (score 14):

Firstly, Underscore doesn't use that implementation anymore. It optimizes to `typeof` unless `typeof /./` returns `function`, as it did atleast in [older versions of Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5054396/320615)

You can find this in the source code: http://underscorejs.org/underscore.js

```
// Optimize `isFunction` if appropriate.
  if (typeof (/./) !== 'function') {
    _.isFunction = function(obj) {
      return typeof obj === 'function';
    };
  }
```

New jsperf: http://jsperf.com/comparing-underscore-js-isfunction-with-typeof-function/3

It still shows quite a performance hit in FF (but MUCH less than the naive implementation you posted in the question), which is due to the overhead of a function call vs just inlining code.

Comment: Testing in Chrome 27.0.1453.110 on Mac OS X 10.8.3 - ``typeof`` is a winner 
54,472,323
±1.45%
fastest

Comment: @Kosmetika, try wrapping the `typeof` into a simple function which does the same thing and compare. :)

Comment: but anyway why not just simply use ``typeof``?

Comment: @Kosmetika, did you see the link I posted in the first sentence? For compatibility with old Google Chromes.

Comment: @Kosmetika There's no reason not to use typeof. In his interesting answer Dogbert points to a reason that isn't valid anymore (unless you manage to run an old version of Chrome).