# why is typeof (/./) !== 'function' used in underscore

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

I was reading through the source for the [`_.isFunction()`](http://underscorejs.org/docs/underscore.html#section-116) function and saw this line:

```
if (typeof (/./) !== 'function') {
```

and I don't understand why it's there. `/./` is a regex that always seem to have the type `object`. Why wouldn't `_.isFunction` be *redefined* if `/./` type was a `function`?

Comment: Answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5054352/why-use-typeof-for-identifying-a-function/5054396#5054396

Comment: Ah, so the check is to avoid accidentally having regex considered function? Nice. Excellent question.

Comment: "Why wouldn't _.isFunction be defined" - it's being redefined. The original toString() definition is two blocks up.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Some versions of various JavaScript engines have allowed for *calling* `RegExp` as another way of using [`.exec()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec):

```
var pattern = /./;

pattern('abc');
pattern.exec('abc');
```

And, since they were *Callable*, [`typeof` considered them `function`s](http://es5.github.io/#x11.4.3):

> Type of val: Object (native or host and does implement [[Call]])
>   Result: `"function"`

To my knowledge, though, current versions don't exhibit this behavior and will throw a `TypeError`. But, if you're concerned with backwards compatibility, as Underscore is, you may need to check for it.

Comment: @ruakh From what I can tell, they should be paired -- unless the engine used an alt of [`[[Call]]`](http://es5.github.io/#x15.3.4.5.1) to make them callable. Do you know of an example?

Comment: Oops, sorry, I misread the answer that Dogbert linked to, and thought that Firefox 3.6.13 used such an engine. So my above comment is (probably) wrong; I'll delete it.